# How to make QTableWidget fill all available window space and show vertical scroll bar if it's larger, but avoid blank white space if it's smaller?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, qtablewidget

I want my QTableWidget to:

1. Fill all available space inside the window
2. Show vertical scroll bar if it's longer than the provided space
3. Adapt to changing window geometry
4. **Do not show blank white space** underneath, if it's smaller than the provided space (without stretching bottom row).

So basically what I want to see:
[Short table without white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0S3V.png)
[Long table fills no less no more than available and shows scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/031Z5.png)

But I can't achieve these two states simultaneously.
What I get instead:
[Ugly white space beneath the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVZjD.png)
[Table stretches the window itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0n8L.png)
The difference in the two behaviors is in calculating table height manually. If I do so, a long table stretches the window, but otherwise it tries to fill all unused space with blank white.

Here is my minimal code:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
import os
     
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 100)
        # self.tableLabel = QLabel()  # I thought it might help somehow
        self.table = QTableWidget(4, 1)
        self.setTable(4)        
        self.table.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.fewRowsBtn = QPushButton('Few rows')
        self.manyRowsBtn = QPushButton('Many rows')
        self.button = QPushButton('Button')
        self.button.setFixedWidth(120)
        self.fewRowsBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setTable(4))
        self.manyRowsBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setTable(20))
        self.map = QLabel()
        canvas = QPixmap(320, 320)
        canvas.fill()
        self.map.setPixmap(canvas) 
        leftLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        leftLayout.addWidget(self.fewRowsBtn)
        leftLayout.addWidget(self.manyRowsBtn)
        leftLayout.addWidget(self.map)
        rightLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        rightLayout.addWidget(self.button) #, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignBottom)
        generalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        generalLayout.addLayout(leftLayout)
        generalLayout.addLayout(rightLayout)
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(generalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)
        
    def setTable(self, rows):
        self.table.setRowCount(rows)
        # self.table.setFixedHeight(self.tableHeight())
        
    def tableWidth(self):
        tableWidth = self.table.verticalHeader().width() + \
                     self.table.horizontalHeader().length() + \
                     self.table.frameWidth() * 2
        app.processEvents()  # Otherwise verticalScrollBar().isVisible()
        app.processEvents()  # lags one event
        if self.table.verticalScrollBar().isVisible():
             tableWidth += self.table.verticalScrollBar().width()
        return tableWidth
    
    def tableHeight(self):
        tableHeight = self.table.verticalHeader().length() + \
                      self.table.horizontalHeader().height() + \
                      self.table.frameWidth() * 2
        return tableHeight

app = QApplication(os.sys.argv)
mywindow = MainWindow()
mywindow.show()
app.exec()
```

I tried playing with different size policies, but all of them give the behavior mentioned above.
I had a vague idea about placing the table in a label, but I don't know how it could help.

Additionally, one other behavior I don't understand is why adding top or bottom alignment for the button under the table makes available space half the height of the window. As if because of that the QVBoxLayout starts distributing space evenly between it's two items.

I think getting the value of the available space in a given window geometry migth help me adjust table size manually. So at least an advise how to do that could help me.

I use Python 3.9.12 and PyQt 6.3.0

Comment: The "ugly white space" is standard in any view (consider the blank area when you create a new text document: you certainly don't expect the window to resize based on the amount of text written). "As if because of that the QVBoxLayout starts distributing space evenly between it's two items": that's explained in the documentation of [`addWidget()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qboxlayout.html#addWidget): "The default alignment is 0, which means that the widget fills the entire cell", so if you *do* specify the alignment the widget will *not* occupy the entire cell, and the cells will be evenly spaced.